# How to query a ToMany object excuding certain values from the relation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-objectbox

I have a simple structure like this, one Person with many Orders.

If a Person has placed many Orders (with codes 1,2 or 3) how do you return Persons with Orders that match only code 3 i.e.: they haven't ordered 1 or 2?

If I have the code below this will match Persons that have Orders with codes 1,2,3 and 2,3 etc yet I only want Persons that have Order matching code 3.

1. **Person** (Match)

   Order code = 3
2. Person

   - Order code = 1
   - Order code = 2
   - Order code = 3
3. Person

   - Order code = 2
   - Order code = 3

```js
QueryBuilder <Person> builder = getBox().query();

builder.linkMany(
  Person_.orders,
  Order_.code.equals(3));


// or this...

builder.linkMany(
  Person_.orders,
  Order_.code
  .equals(3)
  .and(Order_.code.notEquals(1)).and(Order_.code.notEquals(2)));

final query = builder.build()
  ..offset = page
  ..limit = limit;

List <Person> persons = query.find();
```

I'm sure I am missing something simple here!

Comment: Sorry, I can't really think of a condition that would work (see https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#notable-conditions). An owning object is returned if a single related object matches. Maybe you can solve this by additional filtering using `.where()` on the results?

Comment: Ok thanks for that. In Isar I can do something like the following,  which does what I need `.anyOf([1, 3], (q, int e) => q.ordersElementEqualTo(e))
    .and()
     .not()
     .ordersElementEqualTo(2)`